# How to display a result for my javascript quiz?

Tags: javascript

I have to make a quiz using javascript for my digital technologies class but I'm not sure how to display how many questions the person got correct.
This is my quiz so far.

---

```
function mathquiz() { 
    var qn1 = prompt("[22 x 9] a. 180 b. 98 c. 109 d. 198");
    if (qn1 == "d"){
    alert("That is correct!");
    } else {
    alert("That is incorrect!");
}
    var qn2 = prompt("[9 - 11] a. 2 b. -2 c. 5 d. 3 ");
    if (qn2 == "b"){
    alert("That is correct!");
    } else {
    alert("That is incorrect!");
}
    var qn3 = prompt("[7 x 8] a. 51 b. 60 c. 56 d. 54");
    if (qn3 == "c"){
    alert("That is correct!");
    } else {
    alert("That is incorrect!");
    }
    var qn4 = prompt("[99 x 9] a. 891 b. 900 c. 890 d. 871");
    if (qn4 == "a"){
        alert("That is correct!");
    } else {
        alert("That is incorrect!");
    }
    var qn5 = prompt("[100 + 72] a. 171 b. 72 c. 100 d. 172");
    if (qn5 == "d"){
        alert("That is correct!");
    } else {
        alert("That is incorrect!");
    }
    var qn6 = prompt("[10 x 99] a. 999 b. 900 c. 990 d. 100");
    if (qn6 == "c"){
        alert("That is correct!");
    } else {
        alert("That is incorrect!");
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}


mathquiz()
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your code there?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to paste it before I clicked enter

Comment: I would create a counter and increment it each time a question iscorrect. You can then judt display the counter using `alert();`.

Comment: Could you explain that a little more, I've just started javascript a couple of weeks ago and do not understand it to much.

Comment: Create an integer variable that should count the correct answers. In the if branches, you increment it by 1.

Comment: Don't use too many alert boxes. Actually your code blocks entire web page rendering process until all questions answered by user.

Comment: Thank you to everyone that helped me with this! It's all working now, so I'm not stressing anymore. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Simplified version**

```
function mathquiz() {
    var score = 0, Q = [
        ['d', '[22 x 9] a. 180 b. 98 c. 109 d. 198'],
        ['b', '[9 - 11] a. 2 b. -2 c. 5 d. 3'],
        ['c', '[7 x 8] a. 51 b. 60 c. 56 d. 54'],
        ['a', '[99 x 9] a. 891 b. 900 c. 890 d. 871'],
        ['d', '[100 + 72] a. 171 b. 72 c. 100 d. 172'],
        ['c', '[10 x 99] a. 999 b. 900 c. 990 d. 100']
    ];

    for (var i in Q) if (Q.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if (prompt(Q[i][1]).toLowerCase().trim() === Q[i][0]) {
            score++;
            alert('That is correct!');
        } else {
            alert('That is incorrect!');
        }
    }

    alert('Total score: ' + score + ' of ' + Q.length);
}


mathquiz();
```

Answer (score 0):

hi just this follow will fix your ans

```
function mathquiz() { 
var count = 0;
var qn1 = prompt("[22 x 9] a. 180 b. 98 c. 109 d. 198");
if (qn1 == "d"){
alert("That is correct!");
count ++
} else {
alert("That is incorrect!");
}
var qn2 = prompt("[9 - 11] a. 2 b. -2 c. 5 d. 3 ");
if (qn2 == "b"){
alert("That is correct!");
count ++;
} else {
alert("That is incorrect!");
}
var qn3 = prompt("[7 x 8] a. 51 b. 60 c. 56 d. 54");
if (qn3 == "c"){
alert("That is correct!");
} else {
alert("That is incorrect!");
}
var qn4 = prompt("[99 x 9] a. 891 b. 900 c. 890 d. 871");
if (qn4 == "a"){
    alert("That is correct!");
    count ++
} else {
    alert("That is incorrect!");
}
var qn5 = prompt("[100 + 72] a. 171 b. 72 c. 100 d. 172");
if (qn5 == "d"){
    alert("That is correct!");
    count ++;
} else {
    alert("That is incorrect!");
}
var qn6 = prompt("[10 x 99] a. 999 b. 900 c. 990 d. 100");
if (qn6 == "c"){
    alert("That is correct!");
    count ++
} else {
    alert("That is incorrect!");
}                                                                                                                                                                      
console.log(count);                                                     
}


mathquiz()
```

here I'm simply incrementing the count if ans is correct. so at the end in console.log(count) you get the num of correct ans.  here is the fiddle for that [click](https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/10z7x2jv/2/)